# Twitter ID duplication

Tags: random, twitter, duplicates, uniqueidentifier

On Twitter every tweet has an `int64` id assigned to it, but is it generated randomly? And if so, is it possible to have two tweets with the exact same id?

I know 2^64 is a large number, but I just want to know if Twitter has a way of preventing two tweets with the same id or do they rely on the fact that 2^64 is such a large number and having two of the same id's is an extremely small chance?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter uses a combination of timestamp, worker number, and sequence number to compose a unique 64-bit id for tweets. For details, see their engineering blog post [Announcing Snowflake](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2010/announcing-snowflake.html). You can also browse the code on their [Snowflake GitHub repository](https://github.com/twitter/snowflake).

Comment: Thank you, will do!

Answer (score 0):

> These IDs are **unique** 64-bit unsigned integers, which are based on time, instead of being sequential. The full ID is composed of a timestamp, a worker number, and a sequence number.

[documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/twitter-ids.html)